# Storing a text-file in a list, then stripping white spaces, commas and apostrophes in the list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to strip all the white-spaces, commas,  and apostrophes in my list, which came from a text file the user will input. I am trying to filter it to just showing numbers (with no spaces in between).

I am attempting to remove the white-spaces, commas, square brackets, and apostrophes in the variable 'file_strip', but it seems to output the same as 'file_stored_in_list'.

Anyone help me come up with a solution to filter the text file to just numbers? If there are more efficient ways of reading the text file, please let me know! Thanks!

```
filename = input("Input the name of the file: ")
file = open(filename, "r")

#Stores the text file into a list
file_stored_in_list = file.read().splitlines()    
file.close()

#from .txt file: Outputs ['2        7        6', '9        5        1', '4        3        8']
print(file_stored_in_list)


#Attempted to remove white-spaces, tried with commas, sqaure 
brackets and apostrophes, left blank for now
file_strip = [i.strip(" ") for i in file_stored_in_list]

#Outputs the same ['2        7        6', '9        5        1', '4        3        8']
print(file_strip)
```

Comment: Use the `strip(" ")`, then follow up by removing all that is not 0-9 from your result strings with a RegEx... Also you can first remove the multiple spaced from your results, also with a RegEx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oops... you are trying to remove characters that do not exist in the file!

I would bet a coin that the content of the file is just:

```
2        7        6
9        5        1
4        3        8
```

But you read it with:

```
file = open(filename, "r")

#Stores the text file into a list
file_stored_in_list = file.read().splitlines()    
file.close()
```

From there on, `file_stored_in_list` is a nice list of nice strings. To make sure of it, just print it line by line:

```
for line in file_stored_in_list:
    print(line)
```

But when you print a list, python prints square brackets (`[]`) around the list, and prints the *representation* of the elements. And the representation of a string is that string enclosed in quotes...

BTW, the correct way of reading a file line by line is:

```
with open(filename) as file:
    for line in file:
        # process the line...
```

Answer (score 1):

one way of approaching this is with a translation:

```
translation = str.maketrans("", "", " \t,[]'")
file_strip = [item.translate(translation) for item in file_stored_in_list]
```

another way is to use regular expressions:

```
import re
reg = re.compile(r'\D') # \D is anything other than digits
file_strip = [re.sub(reg, '', item) for item in file_stored_in_list]
```

It's worth noting that `strip(" ")` doesn't work in the way you expected - it will only remove spaces from the beginning and end of your string. See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip).

Answer (score 0):

A regex sub should do the trick.

```
import re
mylines = []
with open(myfile) as f: #better, more pythonic
    mylines = f.readlines()

clean_lines = []
clean_lines = [re.sub(r"\s+", " ", l) for l in mylines]
```

This worked for me when i tried:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r"\s+", " ", "a      b      c")
'a b c'
```